# Invoke wso2 admin services SOAPUI

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I m working on wso2 admin services. I get url as `http://localhost:9763/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl` for AuthencticationAdmin.

Now, when I hit the login operation, with admin,admin,127.0.0.1, I get true as return.

ESB console shows logged in.

Now, when I hit logout operation, I dont get any response.

Also I notice that header of the response does not contain any session ID.

My ESB is 4.6.0.

login request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aut:login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <aut:username>admin</aut:username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <aut:password>admin</aut:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <aut:remoteAddress>127.0.0.1</aut:remoteAddress>
      </aut:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

login response :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:loginResponse xmlns:ns="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
         <ns:return>true</ns:return>
      </ns:loginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the response, when I hit login I see, at bottom I only get 6 elements in header as follows :

```
> Date Tue, 25 Jun 2013 14:31:42 GMT
> Transfer-Encoding chunked
> #status# HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type text/xml; charset=UTF-8
> Connection Keep-Alive
> Server WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
```

Now, I dont get session ID. Can you please point out where m I going wrong?

My scenario is that I want to login to WSO2 and then hit some other admin service operation.

Comment: What version of ESB are you working on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time debugging with the java client (see my other answer), I noticed that the SOAPUI Endpoint was not using the **9443** port that I was using in the Java client.  See the image below.

[image]

The **8243** port was picked up from the WSDL by SOAPUI.

When I changed the SOAP UI Endpoint port from **8243** to **9443**, the JSESSIONID gets returned in the response, as seen below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=573D42750DE6C0A287E1582239EB5847; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 22:14:20 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:loginResponse xmlns:ns="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><ns:return>true</ns:return></ns:loginResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have no idea what the difference is between the ports 8243 and 9443, or why one returns a JSESSIONID and the other doesn't.

Comment: Hey,

Thanks... It worked.. I got the session ID...

I m not even able to logout...

Thanks for the help mate!

Answer (score 1):

You could try accessing the server using a java client.  There is an example [here](http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/how-to-consume-admin-services-in-wso2.html).  You could try this example and dump out the SOAP message to see the difference against what you are seeing in SOAPUI.

I'm wondering if the example [axis client's](https://github.com/pradeepfdo/blog-samples/blob/master/simple-front-end/src/main/java/org/wso2/simplefrontend/core/AuthenticationAdminServiceClient.java) `setManageSession(true)` does some magic on the session:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
            RemoteException, AuthenticationAdminAuthenticationExceptionException {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", 
                        SampleConstants.CLIENT_TRUST_STORE_PATH);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", 
                        SampleConstants.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", 
                        SampleConstants.KEY_STORE_TYPE);

    AuthenticationAdminStub stub = 
          new AuthenticationAdminStub(
                 "https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin");
    ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
    Options options = client.getOptions();
    options.setManageSession(true);

    Login login = new Login();
    login.setUsername("admin");
    login.setPassword("admin");
    stub.login(login);

    ServiceContext serviceContext = stub.
            _getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext().getServiceContext();
    String sessionCookie = (String) serviceContext
                               .getProperty(HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING);

    System.out.println(sessionCookie);      
}
```

The above code prints out something similar to the following:

`JSESSIONID=844ECBED015805A24FF9DBD5F5A56C8D; Path=/; Secure=null; HttpOnly=null`